# Pass state from class component to function component in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a class where I declare:

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    checked: false,
    house: [],
    selectedHouse: null
  };
  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}

handleChange(checked) {
  this.setState({ checked });
}

render() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <TSwitch handleChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} house={this.state.house} houseClicked={this.h}></TSwitch>
    </React.Fragment>

  );
}
```

I then want to set `state.checked` from a child component:

```
function TSwitch(props) {
  const handleChange = (house) => (evt) => {
    props.handleChange(house);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {props.house.map((house) => {
        return (
          <label>
            <span>Switch with default style</span>
            <Switch onChange={handleChange} checked={this.state.checked} />
          </label>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I am able to call handleChange but I want to be able to change the value of `state.checked` from the `<TSwitch/>` component.

Comment: `onChange={handleChange}` should be `onChange={handleChange(house)}`

Answer (score 1):

This is what your parent component should be like:

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    checked: false,
    house: [],
    selectedHouse: null
  };
  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}

handleChange(checked) {
  this.setState({ checked });
}

render() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <TSwitch handleChange={this.handleChange} isChecked={this.state.checked} house={this.state.house}></TSwitch>
    </React.Fragment>

  );
}
```

This is what your child component should look like:

```
function TSwitch(props) {

  return (
    <div>
      {props.house.map((house) => {
        return (
          <label>
            <span>Switch with default style</span>
            <Switch onChange={x => props.handleChange(x)} checked={props.isChecked} />
          </label>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

*NOTE: You are using a `Switch` component, I'm not sure if the variable `x` will be a `boolean` or an `object`, but most probably it should be a `boolean`: `true` or `false`. If this doesn't work, log the value of `x` & see if its an object, and pass the boolean in `props.handleChange`. Although I still think this won't be needed. Good luck!*

Answer (score 0):

### 1.

Let's start with your direct question

> I want to be able to change the value of `state.checked` from the `<TSwitch/>` component

1.1 You've correctly passed your mutator function `handleChange` from the Parent class to `TSwitch` but your abstraction function `handleChange` inside that child, that you've duplicated, is unnecessary and *should be removed* completely.

1.2 Next, going back to the class' `handleChange` function, you need to modify the `handleChange` function definition in the parent component, by fixing the argument you passed it -- which will be the `event` object, passed implicitly since you registered it as a callback to `onChange={handleChange}` inside `Tswitch`. At invocation time, it will be called, and the evt argument that's given to `onChange` from React, will be passed into `handleChange`. But, you don't need it. It carries no information of necessity to you. So I would ignore it entirely.

```
// @ parent component

handleChange(evt) {
  // NOTE: i'm going to ignore the evt, since I don't need it.

  // NOTE: i'm going to use optional callback given by setState, to access prevState, and toggle the checked state boolean value.
  this.setState((prevState) => ({ checked: !prevState.checked }));
}
```

---

### 2.

Now let's clean up your code and talk about some best practices

2.1 You dont' need to be using `React.Fragment` here. Why? because Fragments were introduced in React 16 to provide a declarative API for handling lists of components. Otherwise, they're unecessary abstractions. Meaning: if you're not directly dealing with sibling components, then you don't need to reach for `React.Fragment` just go with a `<div/>` instead; would be more idiomatic.

2.2. If `<TSwitch></TSwitch>` isn't going to have a direct descendent, then you should change your usage syntax to `<TSwitch/>`.

2.3 If 2.2 didnt' get picked up by a linter, then I highly advised you install one.

2.4 You can continue using explicit bindings of your class handlers in your constructor if you'd like. It's a good first step in learning React, however, there's optimal ways to remove this boilerplate via [Babel's transform properties plugins](https://medium.com/@tobiahrex/es6-class-static-props-in-react-7b7480381e06).

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
handleChange(checked) {
  this.setState({ checked:!checked });
}
```